# Forge configuration What to Put in Server Providers=>Amazon=>Key/Secret

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, laravel-forge

I created an Ubuntu server on Amazon AWS.

Then I registered for Forge, and now trying to configure it.

I selected source control to be Bitbucket.

I selected Amazon in Server Provider Section,but now I am not sure what to put in key and secret

[image]

Comment: I could be wrong but have a look at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/managing-aws-access-keys.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to this question,

We need to create a IAM user and opt for api access key and secret.

also remember to give access to at least FullEC2Admin Access to this user before initiating the process to create and provision the server via forge.